# Node promise request works locally but not on lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, request, request-promise

For some reason, the script that I am running locally does not work when uploaded to aws lambda. What's weird is that I neither get an error message nor a result. The request simply seems to get stuck and times out.

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

... async function (username, password) {
  if (await this.login(username, password)) {
    console.log("Logged in") //works locally
    return Promise.resolve();
  } else {
    console.log("Not logged in") // never gets called
  }



Con.prototype.login = async function (username, password) {

  console.log("login")    //gets printed

  return new Promise(resolve => {

    try {

      const ccc0 = this.getCookies()
      console.log("login cookies:", ccc0) //gets printed

      request.post({
        url: `${loginURL}/login`,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Cookie': ccc0
        },
        json: { 'username': username, 'password': password },
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
      }).then((loginResult) => {
        console.log("loginResult") //local reaches here, lambda does not
        resolve(true)
      });

      console.log("Check 2") //gets printed

    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Login failed:") //does not get printed
      console.log(e);
      resolve(false)
    }
  });
}
```

At first I thought of conflicting promises or something in that regard however when even the `console.log`s get beyond that state, what could possibly make the request get stuck like that?

Unless Lambda functions have firewalls or something like that by default, I haven't set up anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was setting a VPC having the potential of breaking your internet connection.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/